# How to specify the number of levels of treeview of Telerik Mvc controls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am trying to work with Telerik Mvc Treeview. Is there a way to specify how many of nested levels  the tree has?  Say I only want a single level on the tree, then when I drag and drop nodes I'd like the treeview to prevent users from dropping the node onto another node so that it becomes child node of that node.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no direct way of telling the TreeView to stay to a strict number of of levels, you can still prevent a node from being dropped on another. A simple way to do this, while it might not work in every case, is to check what "position" the node is being dropped in. The "position" can either be "over", "before", or "after". When a node is being dropped on top of another (which will add it as a child element) it has the "over" position. Knowing that we can do the following:

```
@{Html.Telerik().TreeView()
      .Name("TreeView")
      .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add().Text("Item 1");
          items.Add().Text("Item 2");
          items.Add().Text("Item 3");

      })
      .DragAndDrop(true)
      .ClientEvents(clientEvents => clientEvents.OnNodeDrop("onNodeDropped"))
      .Render();
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onNodeDropped(e) {
        var position = e.dropPosition;
        if (position === "over") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will enforce that you can only re-organize the nodes in the TreeView. You probably need to add code to fit your particular scenario, so here are links to the [Drag and Drop](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-drag-and-drop.html) as well as [Client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-client-api-and-events.html) documentation articles.